# aws eks create cluster error - us-east-1e does not currently have sufficient capacity to support the cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-eks

I am creating the aws eks cluster in the us-east-1 region, already having one cluster with cidr block 10.0.0.0/16 and creating another one with 172.31.0.0/16 in the same region using default vpc. But seeing the below erorr.

[image: us-east-1e, the targeted availability zone, does not currently have sufficient capacity to support the cluster]

This [URL](https://github.com/weaveworks/eksctl/issues/817) says, this issue occurs time to time and others say, there is an issue with eksctl. but I am using aws console and not cli. I know creating the cluster in another region would fix this issue, but i need to create this on us-east-1 region only.

What could be the potential issue? is this related to my account or vpc or anything specific?

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/eks-cluster-creation-errors/

Answer (score 10):

Identify the subnet(s) corresponding to the AZ mentioned in the error message and remove the same subnet from the selected subnet while creating the cluster.

eg: if error is specific to us-east-1e, identify and remove the subnet corresponding to this AZ, in the network setting of the cluster.

this will help you creating the EKS cluster in same region.

Answer (score 5):

Change the region on the top right corner to US East(Ohio) or some region in US West and try again. It will work.

Comment: This is not the correct answer. removing the subnet which corresponds to the specific AZ resolves the issue

Comment: @RohitAgre this is the right answer. Can you answer the question?

Comment: @BillyStalnaker the OP clearly says he is creating the Cluster in us-east-1. changing the zone is not the solution.